# Python - Put a list in a threading module

Tags: python, multithreading, list

I want to put a list into my threading script, but I am facing a problem.

Contents of list file (example):

```
http://google.com
http://yahoo.com
http://bing.com
http://python.org
```

My script:

```
import codecs
import threading
import sys
import requests
from time import time as timer
from timeout import timeout
import time

try:
    with codecs.open(sys.argv[1], mode='r', encoding='ascii', errors='ignore') as iiz:
        iiz=iiz.read().splitlines()
except IOError:
    pass

oz = list(iiz)
def nnn(url):
    hzz = {'param1': sys.argv[2], 'param2': sys.argv[3]}
    po = requests.post(url,data=hzz)
    if po:
            print("ok \n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    for i in range(1):
        t = threading.Thread(target=nnn, args=(oz,))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify what elaborate on exactly what you're trying to achieve.

I'm guessing that you're trying to request urls to load into a web browser or the terminal...

Also you shouldn't need to put the urls into a list because when you opened up the file containing the urls, it automatically sorted it into a list. So in other words, the contents in iiz are already in the list format.

Personally, I haven't worked much with the modules you're using (apart from time), but I'll try my best to help you and hopefully other users will try and help you too.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i want send post request to a sitelist via multithread

Comment: Hi Angel, I just noticed your script is trying to search for more than one file, is this your intention?

Comment: So, just to clarify, you want to send post data to search for content on these websites?

Comment: Or do you want to send login data?

Comment: Also, please rename your variables, so that they make sense. For example iiz could become url_list. I'll submit an edit suggestion and see if you like it or not.

Comment: Ok, so I've suggested a better (and probably much easier) way to read from the file containing the urls. You may approve it if you want to.

Comment: hi bro, i want send post data, do you have skype account ?

Comment: It depends what time zone you're in

Comment: Also what type of post data do you want to send. For example to send credential post data is different to sending query data.

Comment: Query Data is when you search for something on a search engine like Goggle, Yahoo and Twitter.

Comment: So in other words, what do you plan to achieve when sending the post data? For example, to search on a website, login to a website, perhaps upload a file. It really does depend on what you want.

Comment: it's query in php, for example : <?php $angel = $_GET['angel']; echo $angel; ?>

Comment: Do you mind sending me a url to all of the php code? or is that it?

Comment: sorry i can't send it:( , you have skype account?

Comment: I need to create a new one to use for non-private reasons, in the meantime, see if you can copy the url instead of the php code. There shouldn't be any reason why you can't just copy-and-paste the url in the address bar?

Comment: it's a demo:http://cms.ttvappelscha.nl/includes/z.php , parameters: param1,param2

Comment: OK, if I give you my eMail, can you send the code behind the php to me?

Comment: If you want to contact me on skype: it's jps13laptop.

Comment: Also, if you're sending the code, via skype, please let me know in this comments section as I only set the skype account up for this reason.

Comment: i sent contact request in skype